# json square brackets to xml attribute

Tags: json, xml

I Am having problems figuring out how to format square brackets [] in JSON to an XML attribute. I know how to format curly brackets e.g.

JSON:

```
"site": {
    "name": "Main",
}
```

XML:

```
DataColumn Value="Excel[1]" AttributeName="site[&quot;name&quot;]"
```

However i do not know how to do the same for `[]` brackets e.g.

JSON:

```
"communicationItems": [
{        
    "id": 123456,
    "type": 
},
{  
    "id": 1,                
    "name": "Email"            
},       
{
    "value": "test@test.com",       
}]
```

XML:

How would i write the name and value in XML?

Comment: There is no XML in your question. Or do you mean `<DataColumn Value="Excel[1]" AttributeName="site[&quot;name&quot;]">`?

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways of mapping JSON structures to XML: there is no exact one-to-one mapping that will always give the right answer (nor is there a right answer). For example, your mapping of JSON objects (curly braces) to XML attributes fails if you have properties whose names are not valid in XML (for example `{"date of birth": "1999-12-01"}`, so it cannot be said to be the "right" way of doing it in all circumstances.

For very simple arrays such as `[1, 5, 12]` you might choose an XML list-valued attribute with space-separation, for example `data="1 5 12"`. For anything more complex you will want a sequence of child elements.

Your example is rather strange because the array only has one member. If it had more than one, it might turn into:

```
<communicationItems>
  <item id="123456">
    <type id="1" name="email"/>
  </item>
  <item id="123457">
    <type id="1" name="phone"/>
    <type id="2" name="fax"/>
  </item>
</communicationItems>
```

But it's entirely up to you.